# Extracting data from Postman using Python or R

Tags: r, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, postman

I just start exploring Postman. Just curious, is it possible to extract data from postman using Python or R?

Thanks

Comment: This is pretty much [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library"*. Is there a way to revise your question and remain without the bounds of the SO topic "boundary"?

Comment: Can you define more precisely what is meant by "extract data from" ?

Comment: Hi, sorry. I did not explain the question clearly.

Is there any library in python and R, that I can directly read JSON format that we get from POST request in Postman.